# How can I get structure of database without using dump and backup queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, remote-access, dump

I need to have a copy of db structure from remote machine on my computer. I don't have an access to create a dump file (my coworkers too) also I can't connect to database. Is there any way to get the database structure? (snapshot isn't a solution because db is huge)

Comment: It highly depends on the database you’re using: Please add the appropriate database tag to your question.

Comment: I work with Postgre db.

Comment: `psql` with the `--schema-only` option? - But if you can not connect to the database, there is no way you can extract that yourself. You will have to ask someone who can connect to the database

Comment: My colleegues can't perform this operation because they don't have such rights.In fact they'll recieve them by the next week, but I'm pressed for time and need to get it done asap.